# Mesh analysis LaTeX circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

So I am trying to create a very simple circuit. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz,siunitx}% cfr: these seem necessary but what else?
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.15}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.4}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0)
  to[I,i=$1 \mA$,] (0,5) % The voltage source
  to[short] (0,5)
  to[short] (4,5) % The resistor
  to[R=$ 1\kilo\ohm$,] (4,0) % The resistor
  to[short] (0,0);
  \draw (4,5)
  to[R=$1\kilo\ohm$] (8,5) % The resistor
  %to[short] (8,5)
  to[R=$10 \kilo\ohm$] (8,0) % The voltage source
  to[short] (0,0);
  \draw (8,5)
  to[R=$1 \kilo\ohm$] (14,5) % The voltage source
  to[R=$1 \kilo\ohm $]  (14,3)
  to[cV=$A V_{in} $]  (14,0)
  to[short] (0,0);
  \draw (10,5)
  to[short] (16,5) node[anchor=west]{A}
  to [open,o-o] (16,0)node[anchor=west]{B}
  to[short] (0,0);
  \draw [red,latex-] (2,2) node[above,color=red]{$i_2$} arc(-90:145:5mm)
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

All that I would like to do is be able to write `i_1, i_2,i_3` inside the drawn thin circle to denote current flowing throughout enouch mesh.

When I try to put a circle arrow, I get an error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See, if my answer on question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324583/mesh-analysis-latex-circuitikz can help you

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to turn your code into a complete MWE. I've added `circuitikz` and `siunitx` to the preamble, but I'm still getting undefined control sequences. What do I need to load in addition? Also, what should `enouch` say?

Comment: Maybe `siunitx` doesn't even help. I get a different error, but at the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a lot of time getting your code to compile, so perhaps the fact that I don't understand the question now I've compiled it is only to be expected. I don't know how a circle can be 'thin'. I thought you might mean an ellipse, but there doesn't seem to be one.

So maybe you want to add `i_1` and `i_3` to the circle containing `i_2`. I wondered if you wanted additional circles, but that wouldn't make sense. If you know how to make one, you could obviously make another two. So I can only think the problem is to add additional labels on the same circle.

Something like this:

[image: more labels]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,european]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.15}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.4}
\begin{circuitikz}[european currents]
  \draw (0,0)
  to [I, i=1<\milli\ampere>] (0,5) % The voltage source
  to [short] (0,5)
  to [short] (4,5) % The resistor
  to [R=1<\kilo\ohm>] (4,0) % The resistor
  to [short] (0,0)
  (4,5)
  to [R=1<\kilo\ohm>] (8,5) % The resistor
  to [R=10<\kilo\ohm>] (8,0) % The voltage source
  to [short] (0,0)
  (8,5)
  to [R=1<\kilo\ohm>] (14,5) % The voltage source
  to [R=1<\kilo\ohm>]  (14,3)
  to [cV=$A V_{in} $]  (14,0)
  to [ short] (0,0)
  (14,5)
  to [short] (16,5) node [anchor=west] {A}
  to [open, o-o] (16,0) node [anchor=west] {B}
  to [short] (0,0);
  \draw [red, Latex-] (2,2) node [above] {$i_3$} arc (-90:145:5mm) node [midway, left] {$i_2$} node [near end, below left] {$i_1$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't write a good explanation, I want to draw something like this [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Mesh_Analysis_Example3.PNG)

Comment: Try replacing `\draw [red, Latex-] (2,2) node [above] {$i_3$} arc (-90:145:5mm) node [midway, left] {$i_2$} node [near end, below left] {$i_1$};` with `\draw [red, Latex-] (2,2) arc (-90:145:5mm) node [midway, below left] {$i_1$};
\draw [red, Latex-] (6,2) arc (-90:145:5mm) node [midway, below left] {$i_2$};
\draw [red, Latex-] (11,2) arc (-90:145:5mm) node [midway, below left] {$i_3$};`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
      \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
       \usepackage{amsmath}
       \usepackage{amsthm}
         \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}
 \begin{center}
 \ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/height=0.15}
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width=0.4}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7]
 \draw (0,0)
      to[I,i=$1 \mA$,] (0,5) 
      to[short] (0,5)
      to[short] (4,5)     
      to[R=$ 100\ohm$,] (4,0) 
      to[short] (0,0);          
\draw (4,5)          
     to[R=$1\kilo\ohm$] (8,5) 
     to[R=$1 \kilo\ohm$] (8,0)
     to[short] (0,0);       
  \draw (8,5) 
      to[R=$10 \kilo\ohm$] (14,5)
      to[R=$1 \kilo\ohm $]  (14,3)         
      to[cV=$A V_{i} $]  (14,0)
      to[short] (0,0);     
 \draw (10,5)         
     to[short] (16,5) node[anchor=west]{A}
     to [open,o-o] (16,0)node[anchor=west]{B}
     to[short] (0,0);
\draw [red, Latex-] (2,2) arc (-90:175:5mm) node [midway, below left]                {$i_1$};
\draw [red, Latex-] (6.3,2) arc (-90:175:5mm) node [midway, below left]         {$i_2$}; 
 \draw [red, Latex-] (11,2) arc (-90:175:5mm) node [midway, below left]             {$i_3$};
\end{circuitikz}
\label{1.1}
```

\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}